# What does the "series" represent for a chart

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

Im busy creating some charts to go on my silverlight application and would just like to know what the .Series[0] represents in the following piece of code

```
PieSeries pieSeries = ((PieSeries)chart.Series[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the documentation for the control you're using? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Sec, `.Series[0]` means to access the `Series` property, which is an array or list type or indexer, where you want to access the first (zero-based) element (0).

Comment: Ill read up on more, Thank you.